# Как из строки брать по 2 символа

Tags: python

К примеру у меня есть переменная со строкой

```
a = "Hello World"
```

и мне надо что бы выводило

```
he
ll
o 
wo
rl
d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in range(0, len(a), 2):
    print(a[i:i+2])
```

или так

```
from itertools import zip_longest

print('\n'.join(''.join(i) for i in zip_longest(*([iter(a)] * 2), fillvalue='')))
```

Answer (score 3):

Другой вариант - воспользоваться модулем [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html)

```
import textwrap    


a = "Hello World"
print('\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(a, 2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

В качестве <s>изврата</s>альтернативного варианта:

```
from io import StringIO

a = StringIO("Hello World")

while True:
    s = a.read(2)
    if not s:
        break
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'hello world'
for num in range(0, len(string), 2):
  print(string[num : num + 2])
```